# evitar que caduque sesion en php

Tags: php, session, cookies, setcookie

tengo un login con email y contraseña y cuando verifico que el usuario se encuentre en la base de datos creo una nueva sesion y con un header llevo a la pagina de bienvenida(todo funciona correctamente pero cuando navego en otra pagina fuera de mi proyecto o salgo del navegador la sesion caduca y me envia nuevamente al login). probe con muchos codigos:

- session_set_cookie_params(0);
- setcookie("COOKIE_INDEFINED_SESSION", TRUE, time()+31622400);
      setcookie("COOKIE_DATA_INDEFINED_SESSION[nombre]", $nombre, time()+31622400);

y algunos otros códigos que parecen funcionar a los demás pero en mi pagina no... ademas revise en phpinfo() y la sesion dice: "mantener viva" y dice que no caduca.

este es mi código de comprobación:

```
if ($numero==1){
    setcookie("COOKIE_INDEFINED_SESSION", TRUE, time()+31622400);
    setcookie("COOKIE_DATA_INDEFINED_SESSION[nombre]", $nombre, time()+31622400);

    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();

    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $password = $_POST["contrasena"];

    $_SESSION['nombre']= $nombre;
    header("Location:juego1.php");
}
```

y en la página juego1 solo tengo que si no hay algo en session(nombre) vuelva a index. y tengo también un session_start() fuera de ese if.

Comment: ya probaste modificando los paramentros del los archivos php.ini, o del .htacces, en la parte que se confiura el tiempo de sesion y todas esas cosas. te dejo un enlace que a mi me ayudo https://www.rafalinux.com/?p=1529

Comment: La sesión expira cuando cierras el navegador, precisamente para persistirla tienes que establecer `session_set_cookie_params` a un valor distinto de cero. Prueba algo así: `$lifetime=600;
  session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
  session_start();` o simplemente: `session_set_cookie_params(600);` . Está de más decir que en vez de `600` puedes poner el valor de tu conveniencia. Para más detalles [revisa el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) y las notas de contribución.